# How do I apply the function I wrote to this image? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, function

The function I wrote is meant to turn every pixel in a given image black:

```js
function setBlack(pixel) {
    pixel.setRed(0)
    pixel.setBlue(0)
    pixel.setGreen(0)
    
    return pixel;
}
```

I defined an image:

```js
var img = new SimpleImage("drewRobertOrig.png");
```

Then tried to call my function:

```js
for (var pixel of img.values()) {
    img.setBlack();
}
```

And got this error: setBlack.pixel is not a function. I'm new to JavaScript so the syntax is difficult for me.

Comment: To use your function as it is defined, it would be `setBlack();`, with some parameter. I understand that that is not too helpful, but that's how you would use that function. If you want to make a "function" for that image class, you have to overwrite its prototype...

Comment: Which should be something like `SimpleImage.prototype.setBlack(pixel) = function (pixel) {... return ...}` provided that pixel is defined in the SimpleImage class. But setters usually don't return anything... so you shouldn't include the return statement. I am looking online for the SimpleImage class, but I am not seeing it... I would just use the Image class.

Comment: Can you link what library you're using? I'd like to refer to docs of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just need to pass the pixel parameter to the setBlack function. Right now you are calling it with no parameters. It wants a pixel parameter. Also, you are calling it as a member method of `img` when it appears to be a separate function.

Change this:

```
for (var pixel of img.values()) {
    img.setBlack();
}
```

To this:

```
for (var pixel of img.values()) {
    setBlack(pixel);
}
```

And see if that works. Not sure what library you are using for this. Are you using a Canvas object?

Are you using [this library](https://github.com/wadefagen/SimpleImage)?

Comment: This worked for me, thank you! I'm using [this custom library](https://www.dukelearntoprogram.com//course1/doc/) from DukeLearnToProgram

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your function is accessible to your `for` loop code, you need to use `setBlack()` as a standalone function, rather than calling it like a `SimpleImage` prototype function.

---

In JavaScript, when you call a function like this:

```text
[object].foo();
```

You're invoking what's known as [a *prototype* function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes). This means that, instead of looking at previously declared stand-alone functions, like your declaration of `setBlack()`, your code will instead look for a method defined by the prototype of the object you're invoking it on.

In this case, by calling `img.setBlack()`, your code is basically going to go look for a definition of a function called `setBlack()` as defined by `SimpleImage`, which doesn't exist (thus throwing your error).

What you likely want to do here is call `setBlack(pixel)` instead, which will call the function you've defined with the argument `pixel` provided by your `for` loop.

```js
function setBlack(pixel) {
    pixel.setRed(0)
    pixel.setBlue(0)
    pixel.setGreen(0)
    
    return pixel;
}

var img = new SimpleImage("drewRobertOrig.png");

for (var pixel of img.values()) {
    setBlack(pixel);
}
```